# How to run a node as a background process?

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to write a program in which a main publisher node will use the system function to run multiple subscriber nodes. I would like to use something like: "rosrun <pkg_name> <node_name> &", however this doesn't work for me and the subscriber node still runs in the same terminal window. How can I change the command so that it executes in the way i described? I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236229/how-to-run-a-node-as-a-background-process?/) by [icepaka89](https://answers.ros.org/users/26952/icepaka89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the `system()` call block when it executes? If not, then the command is running in the background.

Keep in mind that "background" does not imply spawning a different terminal window or logging to disk by default. The process will use the same terminal as its parent.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [icepaka89](https://answers.ros.org/users/26952/icepaka89/) on 2016-06-06**:
No, even when I put the statement in a system call, the output from the node still appears in the terminal window and I cannot run other nodes

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-06**:
What do you mean by "cannot run other nodes" ? Does a second `system()` command fail? Does it stop the other node that's already running? Do you expect to be able to run other nodes in the same terminal?